# Pigeon Hole Principle in Unit Disk

Tags: complex-analysis, pigeonhole-principle

Let $n$ be a natural number such that $n \ge 2$ and given complex number $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n$ that is contained in an open unit disk centered at origin. Prove that there exists $\epsilon_l = \pm 1$ with $l = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{l=1}^n \epsilon_l z_l\right|\le\sqrt{3}
\end{align*}